# Why TestNG complains on using @QAFDataProvider

Tags: java, testng, qaf

```
@QAFDataProvider(dataFile = "src/test/resources/data/logintestdata.csv")
@Test(testName="testLoginPage", description="Login Page landing validation", priority=1, groups={"SMOKE"})
public void testLoginPage(Map<String, Object> data) {       

    // QAF - Qmetry Automation Framework calls

      get("/"); // Check base url in src/test/resources/application.properies file

      verifyText("login.box.header", "Sign In");
      verifyLinkWithTextPresent("Or Sign Up");
      verifyPresent("login.input.username");
      verifyPresent("login.input.password");
      verifyPresent("login.button.submit");
}
```

[Error] org.testng.TestNGException:
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [testLoginPage] with [interface java.util.Map].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-depend
ency-injection
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.checkParameterTypes(Parameters.java:244)
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:172)
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.createParameters(Parameters.java:458)
        at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:568)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1293)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1020)
        at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1110)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
        at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: if I remove parameter from the method, then it doesn't error out. But the question is how can I use the data from dataFile inside the test method body. e.g. data.get("username") and data.get("password")

Comment: Could you show the entire class?

Comment: Which version of QAF and TestNG you are using? Also make sure you are providing correct path of the file may be `resources/data/logintestdata.csv`.

Comment: QAF version - 2.1.13, TestNG version - 6.10. I have overridden the default path of data file into pom file as below. I believe this works fine as all my properties and locator files are being successfully read and loaded by WebDriverTestCase class.
<systemPropertyVariables>
<application.properties.file>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</application.properties.file>
</systemPropertyVariables>

Comment: Try changing method argument from Map<String, Object> to Map<String, String> as you are using 2.1.13 or update qaf version to 2.1.14

Comment: Still not working using both ways.

Comment: Can you share entire log as well as your java class?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already noticed your method does not work with java.util.Map as parameter. Have you tried to use a DataProvider instead?

Here a short example:

```
@DataProvider(name = "data")
public static Object[][] dataProvider() {
    return new Object[][] { { "key1", "value1" }, { "key2", "value2" }};
}

@Test(dataProvider = "Authentication")
public void testLoginPage(String key, String value) {     
  //do something
}
```

The method testLoginPage gets called once for each key value pair in your data provider. Not sure if it works with java.util.Map as well.

Comment: Thanks. But I want to use QAFDataProvider instead of TestNG DataProvider.

Comment: Why can't you use the TestNG DataProvider?

Maybe you could try using both?
Using your QAFDataProvider method to call a TestNG DataProvider and use that in your test method.

Comment: I want to use only one of them and using QAFDataProvider has an advantage of not writing code to read and load data.

Comment: Here is the QAF doc reference for using QAFDataProvider. [link](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/maketest_data_driven.html#java) The document suggests that it should work that way, but why it is giving TestNG error?

Comment: @cjayswal please help.

Comment: Try changing method argument from Map<String, Object> to Map<String, String> as you are using 2.1.13. refer 2.1.13 documentation.